# jpql don't load Blob

Tags: java, orm, jpa, lazy-loading, blob

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Item.findAll", query = "select i from Item i"),
})
public class Item implements Serializable, WithId, WithNameDescription {
    @Lob
    byte[] photo;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    TextualInfo english = new TextualInfo();
// more entry field, getters and setters
}
```

When I call the Query `Item.findAll`, I assume that all the bytes[] get into memory. But I won't use it. So I don't want to fetch it. Is there a way, how to specify the fact that I want lazily load the photo **in the jpql** query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, persistent properties are loaded eagerly and you can't control this from JPQL. However, you can *try* to change the default behavior and make the `photo` lazy with the `Basic` annotation. From the JPA specification:

> #### 9.1.18 Basic Annotation
>
> The Basic annotation is the simplest
>   type of mapping to a database column.
>   The Basic annotation can be applied to
>   a persistent property or instance
>   variable of any of the following
>   types: Java primitive types, wrappers
>   of the primitive types,
>   java.lang.String,
>   java.math.BigInteger,
>   java.math.BigDecimal, java.util.Date,
>   java.util.Calendar, java.sql.Date,
>   java.sql.Time, java.sql.Timestamp,
>   byte[], Byte[], char[], Character[],
>   enums, and any other type that
>   implements Serializable. As described
>   in Section 2.1.6, the use of the Basic
>   annotation is optional for persistent
>   fields and properties of these types.
>
> ```
> @Target({METHOD, FIELD}) @Retention(RUNTIME)
> public @interface Basic {
> FetchType fetch() default EAGER;
> boolean optional() default true;
> ```
>
> The `FetchType` enum defines
>   strategies for fetching data from the
>   database:
>
> ```
> public enum FetchType { LAZY, EAGER };
> ```
>
> The `EAGER` strategy is a requirement
>   on the persistence provider runtime
>   that data must be eagerly fetched. The
>   `LAZY` strategy is a *hint* to the
>   persistence provider runtime that data
>   should be fetched lazily when it is
>   first accessed. The implementation is
>   permitted to eagerly fetch data for
>   which the `LAZY` strategy hint has
>   been specified. In particular, lazy
>   fetching might only be available for
>   `Basic` mappings for which
>   property-based access is used.

Something like this:

```
@Lob @Basic(fetch=LAZY)
public byte[] getPhoto() { return photo; }
```

But as mentioned in the spec, this is just a hint and might not be supported. In that case, an alternative would be to use a lazy loaded **mandatory** one-to-one association with another entity (holding the blob).

#### References

- JPA 1.0 specification

  - Section 9.1.18 "Basic Annotation"
  - Section 9.1.19 "Lob Annotation"

Comment: So basically, it's not possible with jpql?

Comment: @coubeatczech No, this is not possible without modifying the code, this is not something you can control from JPQL. I clarified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In EclipseLink you can control that using FetchGroups. To use it add the EclipseLink's specific `FetchGroup` annotation on top of the entity class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
@FetchGroup(name="personWithNoBlobs",attributes={@FetchAttribute(name="firstName"),@FetchAttribute(name="lastName"),@FetchAttribute(name="address")})
public class Person
```

Either weaving need to be enabled or you Entity class need to implement the `FetchGroupTracker` interface provided by EclipseLink. To use the fetch group in JPQL use this:

```
query.setHint(QueryHints.FETCH_GROUP_NAME, "personWithNoBlobs");
```